# Chrome autoscroll to multiple select with selected option

Tags: html, scroll, html-select

I have an issue with the `<select>` element. When I set the `multiple` attribute, Chrome automatically scrolls to the last `<select>` that has an `<option>` with the `selected` attribute.

ex: http://jsfiddle.net/j1yrxzpp/

```
<select multiple="multiple">
    <option selected="selected">1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
```

Have you any ideas about this ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug for this issue https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=423256